# Android - Copy image to clipboard, anyone got this working?

Tags: java, android, image, clipboard, pasteboard

I am trying to copy a image file from my apk to the clipboard.

Here is how I am approaching it (roughly, i'm using a content provider locally which is out of the scope of the question.

```
        ClipboardManager mClipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "Image/jpg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filename.getAbsolutePath());
        ContentResolver theContent = getContentResolver();
        Uri imageUri = theContent.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        ClipData theClip = ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "Image", imageUri);
        mClipboard.setPrimaryClip(theClip);
```

With this code two things can happen:

1) java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create new file
2) When pasting it only pastes the URI itself, not the image (even in compatible apps)

I don't see any example of anyone getting image pasting on android working, and I have searched for an answer extensively, both on google and stack overflow.

Can anyone help with this?
I would really appreciate someones assistance here.

PS: If it's just not possible to do I would also like to know that, to save wasting anymore time on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have an option. Use the app SwiftKey as your keyboard on Android (it worked on Android 10). It allow you to access your photos library, so you will need to 1) download the image 2) open whatever app you are using and want to paste the image 3) using your SwiftKey keyboard, click on the "+" signal and then on the "pin" symbol (should be in the first line). 4) Finally, click on "create new" and it will access your photos to insert IN-LINE ANYWHERE.

I know that's not the best solution while on iOS you can just tap copy and paste. But it was the only solution that worked for me. Try for yourself. I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication that such functionality is supported in Android.

The behavior is correct and the uri is the **copied data** not the bitmap.

It depends on whether the place you are pasting in can handle this uri.

Comment: That is correct. I was not implying that I expected the bitmap to be copied to the clipboard. The expected behaviour would be that the URI to the image file ( via a content provider ) would be copied to the clipboard and the app in question would handle the URI > Bitmap set up. My question was more in line with has anyone done that before. It is possible as the native gallery app uses this system and the messaging app handles that URI and processes it into a bitmap to be sent with the message.

Comment: Anyone got any more suggestions?

Comment: visiting an old thread. Anyone got this working - copying an image to clipboard ? I am working on android 4.3 and above.  Gmail is not showing picture at all, I don't know if it is the gmail app or my app which is supposed to copy image to clipboard.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @techtinkerer I just wanna note that for this to work at all, the image should be on the public sd card (or simply accessible to other apps)

Comment: @SherifelKhatib - thanks. I was storing pictures in private storage and was trying to copy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue to the OP is this

```
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "Image/jpg");
```

This is an invalid mime type.  It should be

```
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can not copy that to clipboard because its impossible;
but you can do that by copying that to sdcard and then access that from every where that you want;

here is some code that helped me a lot and can help you too:

```
Context Context = getApplicationContext();
String DestinationFile = "the place that you want copy image there like sdcard/...";
if (!new File(DestinationFile).exists()) {
  try {
    CopyFromAssetsToStorage(Context, "the pictures name in assets folder of your project", DestinationFile);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private void CopyFromAssetsToStorage(Context Context, String SourceFile, String DestinationFile) throws IOException {
  InputStream IS = Context.getAssets().open(SourceFile);
  OutputStream OS = new FileOutputStream(DestinationFile);
  CopyStream(IS, OS);
  OS.flush();
  OS.close();
  IS.close();
}
private void CopyStream(InputStream Input, OutputStream Output) throws IOException {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
  int length = Input.read(buffer);
  while (length > 0) {
    Output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    length = Input.read(buffer);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't always assume that there is an SD card in the device. That makes this an unreliable option.