# Is it possible to copy a video to android clipboard?

Tags: android, clipboard

Referring to the [topic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) that explains about copying data to android clipboard, will it be possible to copy a video/audio file to clipboard.

I assume, video/audio files to be stored in binary values and be binded again to play them as video/audio.

Need your kind suggestion and a feasible solution to copy a video to android clipboard and paste to an editor.

**Objective:**

I am developing an app that will carry videos emojis in a custom keyboard (size <100kb), tapping on which user should be able to copy the video to clipboard and be able to paste in an editor. I have already developed custom keyboard, but was not able to copy a video to clipboard.

[image]

Kindly share your thoughts whether copying video to clipboard is possible. Thanks in advance for all your kind suggestions.

Comment: If Video Copy and Paste is not possible, would it be possible to input video from custom keyboard to context of the app? Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

The [clip board framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste) only allows following types of  data

**Text:** a basic string of text. This is actually a CharSequence, so it can be formatted text supported by corresponding Android built-in style spans. (Custom application spans are not supported and will be stripped when transporting through the clipboard.)

**Intent**: an arbitrary Intent object. A typical use is the shortcut to create when pasting a clipped item on to the home screen.

**Uri:** a URI reference. This may be any URI (such as an http: URI representing a bookmark), however it is often a content: URI. Using content provider references as clips like this allows an application to share complex or large clips through the standard content provider facilities.

That means you can't copy&paste a video from clipboard using other application. how ever 
you can use your own method inside your application for copy&paste a video. You can save the path to the clip board and later you can access it. Please note that it will only works inside your app but not going to work with other applications.

For more details visit this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660771/how-to-copy-images-files-to-clipboard-in-android-any-alternative-methods-steps?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: update: you can copy gifs