# React Native Clipboard - how to copy an image or anything other than text?

Tags: clipboard, react-native, react-native-ios

In React Native, with the Clipboard, how can I place an image in the Clipboard? The only method provided to set Clipboard content is "setString". Can you not set images or other content than strings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to bridge native iOS clipboard API and expose the `setImage` method. To do that you need:

1. Add native module header file `Clipboard.h`:

```html
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
@interface Clipboard : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

2. Add native module implementation file `Clipboard.m`. We needed to copy base64 encoded images but you can adjust the code use any other image representation:

```html
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import "Clipboard.h"

@implementation Clipboard

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(BetterClipboard); // this is how our native module will be named

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addBase64Image:(NSString *)base64Image) {
  UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  [pasteboard setPersistent:YES];
  
  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Image options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

  [pasteboard setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
}

@end
```

3. And then you can use it in your React application:

```html
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
   
NativeModules.BetterClipboard.addBase64Image(base64EncodedImage);
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do the same for Android.

Comment: Way super cool! Is it possible with to get image from clipboard? Did you find out how to do this in android yet? Thanks very much for sharing this!!

Comment: It is possible. I don't want to give you examples of code which I didn't try,  just google for "get an image from pasteboard ios". Then you can create React Native API for it using the same approach with native modules.

Comment: Re Android, here is a short explanation of the situation there https://stackoverflow.com/a/39613285/543280 (unless something changed recently).

Comment: Thanks Ihor very much!