# How to copy an Image or Gif to Android clipboard

Tags: java, android, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I've searched a lot for this but found older questions when Android did not support copying gifs to clipboard.

Is there any way now to copy gifs or images to Android clipboard?

How does SwiftKey do that?

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660771/how-to-copy-images-files-to-clipboard-in-android-any-alternative-methods-steps

Comment: Use `FileProvider` to make your content available as a `Uri`, then [put that `Uri` on the clipboard](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste#PasteContentUri).