# How to accept images in TextField Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

In android, when we take a screenshot, it gets stored in the clipboard. Now if I open WhatsApp, and tap on the message field. My keyboard gives me a suggestion to paste the image from the clipboard, as shown below.

[image]

I am guessing this is because the TextField somehow tells the OS that it can accept images. How can I achieve the same behavior in a TextField of flutter? If not a TextField, is there any way to implement a button that can paste image from clipboard into our app?

I have found a pub package for other platforms - https://pub.dev/packages/pasteboard but it doesn't seem to support android.

Comment: check this post it might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432586/clipboard-an-image-in-flutter

Answer (score 2):

very good question, on the bleeding edge of flutter

to get this functionality switch to the flutter master channel (command `flutter channel master`), this will now include [PR 110052](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/110052) which adds this functionality.

to use it simply add this to your TextField:

```dart
//...
  contentInsertionConfiguration: ContentInsertionConfiguration(
    onContentInserted : (_){/*your cb here*/}
    allowedMimeTypes: ["image/png",/*...*/],
  }),
//...
```

this will then use the android specific [content commit api](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/image-keyboard) to (as you guessed) tell the OS that your TextField accepts the given mimetypes; gboard will recognize this and suggest the content with fitting mimetypes in your clipboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package it supports all platforms [super_clipboard](https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard)
then customize the process by adding an icon button for example.

follow the installation steps because the plugin uses Rust internally to implement low-level platform-specific functionality

Comment: I followed the installation steps, and tried using it. But `reader.canProvide(Formats.png)` keeps returning `false`, even though I have an image in the clipboard. Have you tried this package on your own? Did it work for android?

Comment: tbh i tried it on desktop Linux and windows and it works very well for me didn't try it yet on android

Comment: using pasteboard instead..... it's super easy and supports all platforms

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, you can use the FlutterClipboard package to interact with the system clipboard.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_clipboard_manager/flutter_clipboard_manager.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My Widget"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Paste the screenshot here",
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
            maxLines: null,
            onTap: () async {
              var clipboardData = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
              if (clipboardData != null && clipboardData.text != null) {
                setState(() {
                  _textEditingController.text = clipboardData.text;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This would work for text, not images. Could you please make sure that you have understood the question correctly?

Comment: it will paste the path so you can use Image.file(File(path))

Answer (score 0):

Copying files to the clipboard is not widely supported; however, as a general standard, some applications follow the rule of copying the path of the file to the clipboard in order to access it.

you can doing something like this.

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  return directory.path;
}

Future<void> _copyFile() async {
   final path = await _localPath;
   Clipboard.setData(new ClipboardData(text: "content://${_localPath}/image.png"));
   return;
}
```

And these are sources I used when I making this answer. It will usefull for you.

[Clipboard an image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432586/clipboard-an-image-in-flutter/68882967#68882967)

[How to copy Images/files to clipboard in android? Any Alternative methods/steps to get this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30660771/how-to-copy-images-files-to-clipboard-in-android-any-alternative-methods-steps/30661133#30661133)

And If you really intersting solve this problem you can write in native functionally and used in flutter with [platform channel](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-c-tab)