# is there way to get copied image to the clipboard in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am making web application where the user can copy images from their computer and when they want to send that image they can ctrl v on the text field to see the image their sending. I tried this using JS method call I guess it worked but now its giving a lot of problems for including JS on flutter so my question is there way to achieve this using only flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the path of the image, then display it using the path copied since copy image directly is not that easy and well supported. (check this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39613285/10488444)).

Another option is to convert the image to `Base64`, then copy to clipboard and using the data to display the image.

In case it is required to copy the image directly, and you already have a JS function doing it, you can explore the interoperability between JS and Flutter Web using the [js](https://pub.dev/packages/js) package. [This article](https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/) is a good start

---

To catch the event when the user presses hot key on his keyboard, check this article out. `FocusableActionDetector` is the widget we can use to detect the keyboard press, and map specific action to it. In this case it's copying the selected picture's path/ Base64 to clipboard.

Comment: does the first the second methods valid if the user just ctrl c on a image on his computer

Comment: @winstonJeyaseelan I've updated my answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pasteboard](https://pub.dev/packages/pasteboard) package:

```
final imageBytes = await Pasteboard.image;
```

Since version 0.1.1 it supports this method on the web client. But not the all types of images are supported, at least on the current version.